# Change target of duplicate flag

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

I've flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030900/get-integer-from-number-string) as duplicated, but when I put the link to dupe question, I click the wrong browser tab and I flagged it with a [this `PHP` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447311/convert-a-number-to-its-string-representation) by mistake, instead of [this `javascript` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447311/convert-a-number-to-its-string-representation).

I changed the autocomment, so OP can go to the correct answer for him, but...
can I change the target of the flag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of today, you **can** change the duplicate link - [*if* you have a gold badge for one of the tags on the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links).

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Once cast, you can only *retract* a close vote. You cannot re-cast or change your vote.

When you gain a gold tag-badge in one of the tags on the post, your vote would have closed the post immediately (this is called 'the dupehammer'), at which point [you can also edit the links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links).

If you don't have a relevant gold tag badge yet (and you don't when your vote didn't have instantaneous effect), you can make it clear in the comment you mis-flagged, or you can try and get some help in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com). Talk to people familiar with the tags and they'll probably close the dupe for you.

Comment: sort of update: ["As of today, you **can**"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344877/839601)