# What's the best response to questions with multiple dupe-hammerable issues?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

If a question can be answered by a duplicate, it should be closed as such. Simple. But what if the code in the question has multiple problems, each of which, if asked in a separate question (as they should be, because it's supposed to be one question per question), could have been closed as a duplicate of a different question? It's impossible to add more than one duplicate target to a single question (via hammer, anyway - if multiple users flag for duplicate closure, all of those are linked, from what I've seen). Is a question with multiple duplicate issues immune to closure? Do askers just have to add a few more artificial problems so that the question now requires a unique answer, hopefully of the "give codez" variety? Because, [as I just saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846058/how-to-make-an-array-of-buttons-which-change-text-upon-clicking-using-tkinter), such an answer is literally just a bulleted list of links to other questions, plus some codez.

My apologies for forgetting to link that example's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38846058/revisions). As you can see, I closed that question as a dupe, and posted the other two duplicate problems in comments. Another gold badge user then reopened the question (obliterating the original dupe target from all but the revision history) and posted an answer consisting of the three links (dupe and two comments) I'd provided, plus a ready-to-use code snippet.

Comment: I'd dupehammer as required and add a comment to the effect that anything NOT covered by the dupetarget should be asked in a *separate* question as required by the guidelines.

Comment: Vote to close as too broad perhaps.

Comment: The added "benefit" of dupehammering is, of course, that it stop answers being added to a question that is too broad.

Comment: As the person who answered said question, I would like to add that I did not have the impression that it was a "give codez" or "too broad" question, neither did it have multiple questions in one. It had one question, upon solving two follow-up problems would have appeared -- one obscured by the first problem and one very likely introduced by the fix to the first problem.

Comment: Sounds like a mess.  VTC as unclear, downvote, vote to delete.

Comment: If a question which needs answers in both question A and B, imagine the question is marked as duplicate of A, it means it can be answered with A and without B, but it is isn't actually, how can it says it is duplicate of A (or B)?

Comment: @amuse You're just restating the question. That is obvious. The problem is that the question is too broad precisely _because_ it could be considered a duplicate of 2 or 3 different questions.

Comment: @tobias_k While I sort of understand where you're coming from and what you're trying to prevent, some classes of users and questions are immune to this treatment without a crystal ball. For example, the user is [already back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857811/getting-a-tic-tac-toe-move-from-a-button-click-in-python-with-tkinter) less than a day later with another problem caused by naive application of "solutions" gained here without actually understanding the code.

Comment: I think this is sort of a recurring theme, in the Python tag at least.

Comment: As I said, I just wanted to help in the best way possible, but I see that helping an individual user might not always be helping SO as a whole. As soon as the question gets closed, I will delete my answer. (Deleting it now might just attract another answer, and being the one who reopened it I'd find it odd to close the question myself.)

Comment: I'm just doubt if the question should be closed as duplicate, because it requires BOTH question A and B to answer, not EITHER A or B, closing it as duplicate seems violate the usage of duplicates, so if it should be closed, I think "too broad" is more fit the case, and of course, whether it is "too broad" just because it needs more than 1 other question to answer is another story (ie.:how many questions to link to reach the criteria of too broad?two? three?or just by personal programming skills?)

Comment: @amuse - Duplicates are kind of like standards, then - the more there are, the less they mean? Personally, I think more duplicates means the questions is more of a duplicate, and it would make more sense to fix the duplicate closure process. I'd like to see the ability to select multiple targets when hammering, and maybe even allow gold badge users to vote on marked duplicates so the most useful/relevant ones rise to the top.

Comment: dupe sledge-hammer?

Comment: @cdkMoose - That's what we have, but I would like a dupe piano, with lots of very precise hammers that I can use as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change target of duplicate flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287980/change-target-of-duplicate-flag)

Answer (score 43):

In order to answer this loaded question, we need to establish a couple of premises:

1. Every simple programming problem has been asked at least once before. Oh, yeah, "new frameworks and libraries emerge every day", but that fact doesn't apply to 99.9% of the questions that get asked every day.
2. Those simple problems have not been asked properly, and often don't get answered properly. Yes, they are recognized as "canonical" by experienced users, because they recognize the problem and the patterns used in the answers, but to an inexperienced user, those questions could as well have been written in Chinese, because the problem statement isn't clear, the code isn't generic enough and answers rarely ever *explain* the problem, its solution and the implementation of said solution, let alone the possible alternatives and drawbacks of each.
3. An awful lot of people asking questions are not experienced enough to break down their problem into the smaller parts that have in fact already been asked, solved and answered. This is part debugging experience, part vocabulary.
4. People don't understand the knowledge base aspect of Stack Overflow and just want to "help" these poor newbies by churning out answers by the dozens a day without, again, properly explaining the code they're posting and why that code might in fact not be the best solution to the poorly described problem of the OP.
5. Answerers that are here for the reputation, or who genuinely believe that they're helping people by Googling the question's title and copy-pasting the code off first hit without attribution and, again, the explanation found at the source, find Stack Overflow so "negative", and try to find the beauty in every question - even if that question has twenty possible answers and should be put on hold and be clarified using comments and editing first.

<sub>Not saying any of those apply to the answer posted to the question linked to here.</sub>

You can't solve #2, because if you edit code in questions and answers, you will get scolded because now the answerer will have to support *your* version of *their* code, and that edit *will* be rolled back. Or because someone doesn't understand your title that better covers the problem, because they always used Google to find that question based on its old title.

So we will **never** have **great** canonicals for most problems, unless someone wants to re-write and support all canonicals.

Given "too localized" isn't a close reason anymore, its alternative in this case is "too broad". This is because the OP is asking: *"Explain me all the gaps in my knowledge that speaks from the wording of my question and the problems in my code, and at the same time, fix my code"*, thus requiring a mini one-on-one course that won't be particularly helpful for anyone who's reading the question after them. Alternatively, it'll just attract ["try this" answers that only contain code dumps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811).

Of course, if you perceive at least one of the OP's problem to be answered in a duplicate, feel free to close-vote as duplicate of that one to at least *partially* solve their "too broad" problem, and point out the rest of the problems with the post in a comment.

This can and will be seen as power abuse by some, and they will start discussing with you why they think you should reopen the question so they can post their answer (*"I know the answer [and it's slightly different from the duplicate], so it can't be unclear/to broad/duplicate..."*). You can safely ignore this discussion as there are no repercussions and the reopen review queue fails just as hard as any other.

I'm not trying to be a negative nancy or anything, but the site seems to delve into *"I have not enough experience or interest to narrow down my problem, so please do that for me and at the same time fix my entire problem"*. The result of that is that factually every question is "too localized", and unhelpful for anyone else (because yeah, the combination of problems and variable names together is unique) and the problem is improperly worded (and thus unfindable for others), and that answers to unique (sub)problems get repeated, copy-pasted, poorly explained and even more spread out over the site than is already the case.

So do we want Stack Overflow to be "hand-held debugging and problem solving on the fly" (a.k.a. a forum) as opposed to an easily searchable knowledge base full of singular high-quality questions and answers? Then perhaps the staff should send out a Public Service Announcement stating "this is now okay", so people won't scramble to Meta to find the proper close reason for such questions and battle in comments about whether such questions should actually be answered.

Comment: My profound apologies. I keep forgetting that question closure history isn't discoverable if the question itself has never been edited via the ordinary edit link. The edit history on a question whose edits consist only of closure/reopening is (AFAIK) only accessible by messing with the question's URL. I did close the question as a duplicate, and it was reopened and answered. I've added this information to my question. Sorry again.

Comment: Oh I've had gold-badgers reopen questions I dupehammered as well, so they could post an answer. When that happens, just run. There's nothing else you can do (being out of close-votes on that question and all that), and obviously they don't agree with you, otherwise they wouldn't have reopened the question. You're not going to persuade them to delete their answer and re-close the question.

Comment: I wish your last 2 paras were a feature request (although it would just get shot down, by the community no less). Despite the fact that askers who have no experience, code riddled with mistakes, and just want a copy-paste solution (and complain loudly at anyone who tries to instruct them) are **the worst kind of questions**, there's a significant underbelly of (particularly new members of) the community stumbling over themselves to make sure they get taken care of, so they're sure to be back. This is apparently what we want now. We **are** a forum.

Comment: "answers rarely ever explain" This does not match my experience. Most answers I see do explain the problem, although I have seen some that don't. This could be a "cultural" phenomenon, where the experience varies between tags. (E.g., maybe it's common that answers provide analysis and explanation in PostgreSQL questions and not so much in Oracle.)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: "*although it would just get shot down, by the community no less*" It would be shot down because, like "Too Localized", it would be too open to *abuse*. There was too much use of "Too Localized" for questions that weren't too-localized at all. It was a catch-all close reason to close questions that some people didn't want to see on the site.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think it was less a matter of *abuse* and more a matter of confusion, but your point mostly stands.

Comment: @NicolBolas And that is solved by them now all being closed as "Too broad", or...?

Comment: @jpmc26 my answering experience lies mostly in the C# tag, which is a copy-paste fest. I read many other tags as well, but given C# is the number three tag with nearing almost a million questions, I see it often.